# How does receive block work?

Tags: erlang

I just had a simple question and I can't seem to find an answer to it. Basically my question is if I have a function recording state (recursive) and I send multiple messages to it, will it keep going through the receive block until it no longer has messages in its "mailbox"?

```
state(Fridge) ->
    receive
        Pat1 ->
            io:format("ok"),
            state(S);
        Pat2 ->
            io:format("not ok"),
            state(S)
    end.
```

So if I'd send to this process 3 messages (Pat1, Pat2, Pat1) using "!" and its not able to go into its loop before receiving messages will it still print out the following?

```
1> "ok"
2> "not ok"
3> "ok"
```

Sorry if this isn't very clearly put, by simplifying the question it might make it hard to picture what I am asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question isn't clear but you seem to be asking whether the process will receive the three messages even if they're sent before the target process has called `receive` — if that's the question, the answer is yes. When you send a message to a process, it goes into that process's message queue until the process calls `receive` to remove it from the message queue and deal with it.

If you call `erlang:process_info(Pid, messages)` where `Pid` is the receiver's process id, you can see what messages are in its queue. You might try this from the Erlang shell.

As an extreme example of message queueing, under some heavy load conditions it can be a source of out-of-memory problems if a receiver can't keep up with a fast sender. Under these conditions, a receiver's message queue might grow without bound until the system runs out of memory.

Comment: Sorry it's hard to explain without an visual example, but that answer my question. Thank you Steve!

Answer (score 2):

Does this answer your question?

```
1> OUT = fun(X) -> io:format(">>> ~p~n", [X]) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.54118792>
2> F = fun X() -> receive foo -> OUT(foo), X(); bar -> OUT(bar), X() end end.
#Fun<erl_eval.44.54118792>
3> P = spawn(F).
<0.38.0>
4> [ P ! X || X <- [foo, bar, foo]].
>>> foo
[foo,bar,foo]
>>> bar
>>> foo
```

A message arrives in the mailbox and then `receive` patterns are applied to the message like the function clause or `case` statement. But unlike those, if none of them match, next message is processed and the previous one left in the message box untouched. Other `receive` clause starts always from beginning of message queue.

```
1> OUT = fun(X) -> io:format(">>> ~p~n", [X]) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.54118792>
2> F = fun() -> receive start -> (fun X() -> receive foo -> OUT(foo), X(); bar -> OUT(bar), X() end end)() end end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.54118792>
3> P = spawn(F).
<0.38.0>
4> [ P ! X || X <- [foo, bar, foo]].
[foo,bar,foo]
5> P! start.
>>> foo
start
>>> bar
>>> foo
```

Note that `foo, bar, foo` is in the queue in the first `receive` but it is not processed. When `start` arrives (last in the queue) second `receive` starts process `foo` and `bar` messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
-module(wy).
-compile(export_all).

state() ->
    timer:sleep(2000),
    io:format("~p~n", [erlang:process_info(self(), messages)]),
    receive
        pat1 ->
            io:format("ok~n"),
            state();
        pat2 ->
            io:format("not ok~n"),
            state()
    end.
main() ->
    Pid = spawn(fun state/0),
    [ Pid ! X || X <- [pat1, pat2, pat1]].
```

You can run this code, from the output you can understand everything.

**Note:**when you send message to a process, the sent messages will be stored in mail box of the process.

```
6> wy:main().
[pat1,pat2,pat1]
7> {messages,[pat1,pat2,pat1]}
7> ok
7> {messages,[pat2,pat1]}
7> not ok
7> {messages,[pat1]}
7> ok
7> {messages,[]}
7>
```

One comments for your code:

```
receive
    Pat1 ->
        io:format("ok"),
        state(S);
    Pat2 ->
        io:format("not ok"),
        state(S)
end.
```

the second clause will not match forever.